# How to show Google's word definition

Tags: google-search

If you type certain words in Google search, for example `loquacious`, Google will show some kind of dictionary definition for it, as well as how to spell the word. But for other words the word definition does not show up, for example `lobster`.

Is it possible to tell google to display the word definition of certain word (like the `loquacious` example)?